# Convert escape characters in strings (like "\\n" - two characters) into ASCII character (newline)

Tags: python, escaping

My program got a string from the command line arguments, that contains many escapes characters.

```
./myprog.py "\x41\x42\n"
```

When I print "sys.argv[1]".
I got on the screen:

```
\x41\x42\n
```

Is there a simple way to do that the program print instead:

```
AB[newline]
```

Comment: First of all, what is `AB[newline]`. Second of all, did you try to `sys.argv[1].encode('ascii')`?

Comment: A is the ascii character for "41" hexadecimal number. B ... for "42" .... I want that my string be processed as if it was directly in a python script.

Comment: Yeah, I see that. Can you review my answer. Does it resolve your problem?

Comment: Yes, I tried decode("hex") and decode("ascii"). Both don't give the expected result.

Comment: Yes that's what i want to print. But I test with python2 and python3 it does not work for me when "\x41\x42\n" is passed as an argument

Comment: The string passed to your program is `'\\x41\\x42\\n'`. I don't think there is a simple way to revert it back into `'AB\n'`. You'll have to split the string by `'\\'`, and treat each element separately (though the hex ones can be dealt with using the same piece of code).

Comment: For example: `print ''.join([chr(int('0'+k,16)) for k in sys.argv[1].split('\\')[1:-1]])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the argument in the following way:

```
./myprog.py $'\x41\x42\n'
```

The `$'...'` notation is allowed to be used together with `\x00`-like escape sequences for constructing arbitrary byte sequences from the hexadecimal notation.

Another way to fix this is to do what @[Barak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1382251/barak-manos) suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30827325/1929635) -- that is converting the `hex` characters.
It just depends on what you find easy for you.

Answer (score 2):

The string passed to your program is `'\\x41\\x42\\n'`.

I don't think there is a simple way to revert it back into `'AB\n'`.

You'll have to split the string by `'\\'`, and treat each element separately.

If your string is always of the form `'\\x..\\x..\\x..\\n'`, then you can do this:

```
print ''.join([chr(int('0'+k,16)) for k in sys.argv[1].split('\\')[1:-1]])
```

Comment: Of course, if you are the user who passes that input to your program, then the answer suggested by @bshuster13 is a better (and cleaner) solution.